# How do I use each line of a text file to select lines with matching string in a second text file?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Suppose I have two text files - active-users.txt and all-user-info.txt

active-users.txt contains only numeric userIDs.

all-users.txt contains userIDs, and additional info fields.

What I need to do is to create a third text file which will contain the complete line of information for every userID in active-users.txt...

I've tried the following, in a bash script and on the command line:

```
for i in $(< active-users.txt)
do
grep $i all-users.txt >> active-user-info.txt
done
```

The broken bit that's driving me bonkers is that the active-user-info.txt output file always contains all of the contents of all-user-info.txt - and I'd expect it to only contain lines including the userIDs in activeUsers.txt

What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't explain what's wrong with your attempt, but `grep -f active-users.txt all-users.txt` should do what you want... (I can turn this into an answer if that's good enough for you!)

Comment: Actually your attempt works for me... But you'll match portions of ids.

Comment: I've tried grep -f as you describe, and that also results in dumping the entire contents of all-users.txt to stdout, or to a file.

Comment: That means that the identifiers in `active-users.txt` *do* match all the *lines* in `all-user-info.txt`. Note that there's no structure here, so `1` in `active-users.txt` would match `1` anywhere in lines of `all-user-info.txt`: it would match `1` or `10` as an identifier, but also `1` in the extra information.

Comment: Stephen - I've tried grep -f, and also tried using the -w to prevent portion matching...
With just -f, I get the same result - output is the entire contents of the master file.
When I add the -w, the output is null.

Comment: For clarity - each 'userID' is actually a cellphone SIM IMSI - a 15 digit number. The 'additional info' in all-user-info inludes PIN#'2, Auth keys, etc. as well as some text strings.

Comment: Also, the IMSI's are - in all but a few cases, sequential, with the first 11 numbers identical, and the last four integers incrementing from 0010 to 5010 (decimal).

Are you saying that any portion of userID can match, unless I use the -w flag?

Comment: No, the user id would have to match in its entirety, but it can match against anything in the lines, not just the user id. See the suggested duplicate for more discussion (`-Fwf` all told).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming *active-users.txt* has no blank lines:

```
grep -f active-users.txt all-users.txt > active-users-info.txt
```

If *active-users.txt* has one or more blank lines in it:

```
grep '.' active-users.txt | grep -f - all-users.txt > active-users-info.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with test files

```
while read LINE; do
    grep "$LINE" all-users.txt >>active-users-info.txt
done <active-users.txt
```

Comment: just noting the difference in case-sensitive grepping that the Q used; don't know if it matters for the sample data

Comment: @JeffSchaller what difference?

Comment: I could have sworn there was a `grep -i` in the Q, but clearly I'm wrong!